# django rest framework ModelSerializer, validations for http PUT and POST

Tags: django, validation, serialization, django-rest-framework, http-put

So I have a model defined as follows:

```
class Subscriber(models.Model):
      client_id = models.IntegerField()
      user_id = models.IntegerField()
      channel = models.ForeignKey(to=Channel, related_name='channel_subscribers')

      class Meta:
          unique_together = ('client_id', 'channel')
```

and the serializer for this model is as follows:

```
class SubscriberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Subscriber
        fields = ('id', 'client_id', 'user_id', 'channel')
```

So

1. I make a `POST` request for subscriber, using, `client_id=1` and `channel_id=1` and `user_id=1`. This result into creation of a `Subscriber` with, say `id=1`
2. Now I want to change user_id for the subscriber created in `step 1` above.
3. So I make a `PUT` request with `client_id=1`, `user_id=2` and `channel_id=1` for `Subscriber` with `id=1`.
4. At this step, serializer throw an error since combination of `client_id` and `channel_id` is not unique which is a constraint put in `Subscriber` model.

I want that when I make a `PUT` request with `id=1`, serializer actually check for this constraint against all the `Subscriber` models except the `Subscriber` with `id=1`.

Does django rest framework provide anything to meet this criteria. Or I have to write different serializers for create and update which I believe is the ugliest solution.

What can be the best solution to this problem provided the model's structure cannot be changed.

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe you're looking for the [UpdateAPIView](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#updateapiview)